# Getting error while retriving items from world server after translation

Tags: workflow, translation-manager, 2013-sp1, worldserver

I have implemented a Translation Manager Plugin (Refereed [Eric's Blog](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/27/sdl-tridion-workflow-translation-manager-integration)) to revoke my workflow activity once the translation is completed. It is working absolutely fine when I am sending a item to world server for translation through workflow.

But getting error message when directly sending any item from CMS without workflow (Please refer below screen shot).

[image: Error Message]

Below is the Translation Manager log details -

> 2016-03-11T17:27:39   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Retreiving translation management system item with id "tcm:5-11407" for language "1023".
>   2016-03-11T17:27:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation An error occured while processing an item: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       Translation Job title: Copy of jfj
>       Translation Job id: 122
>       Translation management system job id: 1130
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Translation.PlugIns.ResumeActivityUponTranslation.OnStateChanged(Object
>   sender, TranslationJobStateChangeEventArgs e)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationJob.ChangeState(TranslationJobState
>   newValue, Boolean validateStateChange)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.RetrieveFromTranslationTask.FinalizeTranslationJob(TranslationJob
>   translationJob)

Event Viewer log -

> The description for Event ID 0 from source Translation Manager cannot
>   be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed
>   on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> An error occured while processing an item: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.     Translation Job title: Copy of jfj
>     Translation Job id: 122     Translation management system job id: 1130
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

Though it is showing the error message but I can see that the item is localized and changed properly.

Please suggest. ( FYI: It works properly if I remove the plugin)

Comment: Have you confirmed the job is still present in World Server - and if it's not, is your code assuming that it is? What is your existing event system code currently doing (example in OnStateChanged - perhaps share the different events) - this will be running irrespective of workflow or manual triggering of the translation job? - you state "I can see that the item is localized and changed properly." - so when your events are removed, all is well.

Comment: My event system is checking the state of translation job. If it is completed then it revokes my workflow. If I am sending any item through workflow then it works fine, But when sending item from CMS then only I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stack trace:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Translation.PlugIns.ResumeActivityUponTranslation.OnStateChanged(Object sender, TranslationJobStateChangeEventArgs e) 
  at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationJob.ChangeState(TranslationJobState newValue, Boolean validateStateChange)
  at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.RetrieveFromTranslationTask.FinalizeTranslationJob(TranslationJob translationJob)
```

it is clear the exception is thrown from your code. So the next step would be to debug your code to understand why it throws the exception.